# Convert command's output in dictionary format in python

Tags: python

This is the output of pexpect.before for the command vnstat.
I store the output of the command(vnstat) in str1 as given below.
Example:

```
p.sendline('vnstat')
str1  = p.before
```

now, the str1 contains the below input data.

```
                     rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
br-int: Not enough data available yet.
eno1:
       Oct '19     17.30 TiB  /   18.22 TiB  /   35.52 TiB  /   78.89 TiB
     yesterday      1.61 TiB  /    1.70 TiB  /    3.31 TiB
         today      1.99 TiB  /    2.05 TiB  /    4.04 TiB  /    5.50 TiB
eno3: Not enough data available yet.
eno2: Not enough data available yet.
eno4:
       Oct '19    155.02 MiB  /    5.16 MiB  /  160.18 MiB  /  355.00 MiB
     yesterday     19.46 MiB  /    1.08 MiB  /   20.54 MiB
         today     14.21 MiB  /     650 KiB  /   14.84 MiB  /      --"
```

I am trying to convert the above data into the dictionary format like the below. Using the colon(:), I want to convert the above input data.

```
Dict1_Key{0} = br-int
Dict1_Value{0} = Not enough data available yet.

Dict1_Key{1} = eno1
Dict1_Value{2} =   Oct '19     17.30 TiB     18.22 TiB     35.52 TiB     78.89 TiB
                   yesterday      1.61 TiB    1.70 TiB     3.31 TiB
                   today      1.99 TiB      2.05 TiB      4.04 TiB      5.50 TiB
...
..
```

Comment: Hi @karthika, welcome to SO. Please read the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to create a question that will be answered.

Comment: where is your code? What result you get with your code?

Comment: as for me main problem is to split all text in groups of lines which start at line which have `:`. When lines are grouped then it is easy split group using `:`

Comment: In case you are interested of getting the values out from the output, it's worth noting that vnStat also provides a json format output with `vnstat --json` which is usually far more trivial to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your problem but in this kind of string main problem can be splitting string to groups of lines which start at line with `:`

When string will be splitted then in every group will be easy to use `:` to create `key` and `value`

This example code splits text in lines and group lines

```
text = '''                     rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
br-int: Not enough data available yet.
eno1:
       Oct '19     17.30 TiB  /   18.22 TiB  /   35.52 TiB  /   78.89 TiB
     yesterday      1.61 TiB  /    1.70 TiB  /    3.31 TiB
         today      1.99 TiB  /    2.05 TiB  /    4.04 TiB  /    5.50 TiB
eno3: Not enough data available yet.
eno2: Not enough data available yet.
eno4:
       Oct '19    155.02 MiB  /    5.16 MiB  /  160.18 MiB  /  355.00 MiB
     yesterday     19.46 MiB  /    1.08 MiB  /   20.54 MiB
         today     14.21 MiB  /     650 KiB  /   14.84 MiB  /      --'''

all_groups = [] # list for all groups
group = [] # create list for first group

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if ':' in line: # line with `:` starts new group
        all_groups.append(group) # add previous group to list of all groups
        group = [] # create empty list for new group
    group.append(line.strip()) # add line to current group
all_groups.append(group) # add last group to list of groups

# --- display groups ---

for group in all_groups:
    text = '\n'.join(group)
    print(text)
    print('---')
```

Result

```
rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
---
br-int: Not enough data available yet.
---
eno1:
Oct '19     17.30 TiB  /   18.22 TiB  /   35.52 TiB  /   78.89 TiB
yesterday      1.61 TiB  /    1.70 TiB  /    3.31 TiB
today      1.99 TiB  /    2.05 TiB  /    4.04 TiB  /    5.50 TiB
---
eno3: Not enough data available yet.
---
eno2: Not enough data available yet.
---
eno4:
Oct '19    155.02 MiB  /    5.16 MiB  /  160.18 MiB  /  355.00 MiB
yesterday     19.46 MiB  /    1.08 MiB  /   20.54 MiB
today     14.21 MiB  /     650 KiB  /   14.84 MiB  /      --
---
```

Now it is easy to split evey group (which has `:`) into `key` and `value`.

Because you use nubmers as keys in your dictionares then you could use list instead of dictionary. And you could keep `key` and `value` together as tuple.

```
data = []

for group in all_groups:
    text = '\n'.join(group)
    if ':' in text:
        key, value = text.split(':')
        value = value.strip()
        data.append((key, value))

        #print('---', key, '---')
        #print(value)              

for item in data:
    print(item)
```

Result

```
('br-int', 'Not enough data available yet.')
('eno1', "Oct '19     17.30 TiB  /   18.22 TiB  /   35.52 TiB  /   78.89 TiB\nyesterday      1.61 TiB  /    1.70 TiB  /    3.31 TiB\ntoday      1.99 TiB  /    2.05 TiB  /    4.04 TiB  /    5.50 TiB")
('eno3', 'Not enough data available yet.')
('eno2', 'Not enough data available yet.')
```

---

Eventually you could use `br-int`, `eno1`, etc. as a key in dictionary instead of numbers

```
data = {}

for group in all_groups:
    text = '\n'.join(group)
    if ':' in text:
        key, value = text.split(':')
        value = value.strip()
        data[key] = value

        #print('---', key, '---')
        #print(value)              

for item in data.items():
    print(item)
```

---

**EDIT:** Eventually you can use regex to split text - `re.split('\n(.*):', text)`

```
text = '''                     rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
br-int: Not enough data available yet.
eno1:
       Oct '19     17.30 TiB  /   18.22 TiB  /   35.52 TiB  /   78.89 TiB
     yesterday      1.61 TiB  /    1.70 TiB  /    3.31 TiB
         today      1.99 TiB  /    2.05 TiB  /    4.04 TiB  /    5.50 TiB
eno3: Not enough data available yet.
eno2: Not enough data available yet.
eno4:
       Oct '19    155.02 MiB  /    5.16 MiB  /  160.18 MiB  /  355.00 MiB
     yesterday     19.46 MiB  /    1.08 MiB  /   20.54 MiB
         today     14.21 MiB  /     650 KiB  /   14.84 MiB  /      --'''

import re

results = re.split('\n(.*:)', text)

results = results[1:] # skip first element (first line)

#for item in results:
#    print('>', item)

data = []

for key, value in zip(results[0::2], results[1::2]):
    data.append((key, value))
    #print('---', key, '---')
    #print(value)

for item in data:
    print(item)
```